# flutter and egrocer version conflict on git

Tags: flutter, git, entity-framework, file, flutter-dependencies

since every version of flutter_paystack from git depends on intl ^0.17.0 and egrocer depends on intl ^0.18.0, flutter_paystack from git is forbidden. So, because egrocer depends on flutter_paystack from git, version solving failed. how to fix??

```
here is my pubspecc.yaml
publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+3

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.6 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  http: ^0.13.4
  connectivity_plus: ^3.0.2
  provider: ^6.0.2
  flutter_svg: ^2.0.0+1
  flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.10.0
  firebase_core: ^2.2.0
  country_code_picker: ^2.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^4.1.2
  otp_text_field: ^1.1.3
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  lottie: ^2.1.0
  geolocator: ^9.0.1 #for user location
  flutter_google_places: ^0.3.0
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.2.0  #for map
  geocoding: ^2.0.4
  speech_to_text: ^6.1.0
  shimmer: ^2.0.0
  photo_view: ^0.14.0
  file_picker: ^5.2.0 #for pick the files for profile picture
  path_provider: ^2.0.11
  url_launcher: ^6.1.5
  share_plus: ^6.3.0
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^5.0.5 #for share product
  intl: ^0.18.0
  razorpay_flutter: any
  flutter_paystack:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/definitelyme/flutter_paystack.git
      ref: a4a33c3dd0a12f46d655a2e63d11e9f20ba82d01
  firebase_messaging: ^14.1.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^13.0.0
  flutter_stripe: ^8.0.0+1
  external_path: ^1.0.3
  open_filex: ^4.3.2
  paytm: ^3.0.1
  version: ^3.0.2
  package_info_plus: ^3.0.2
  awesome_notifications: ^0.7.4+1
  permission_handler: ^10.2.0
  flutter_swipe_button: ^2.1.1+1
  webview_flutter: ^4.0.7
  flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.4.0
  vibration: ^1.7.6
```